# Managing migrations with two Django apps connected to same database?

Tags: django, database, migration

I have two servers / Django apps connected to my one MySql database, `1.example.com` and `2.example.com`. I want to make all the migrations on `1.example.com`, and not have to update the migrations folder / models.py file in `2.example.com` every time I want to make a database change.

What's proper protocol here? Can I just delete `models.py` and `migrations/` from my `2.example.com`? Or is there a Django setting to be aware of.

The apps are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

If your multiple apps are exact copies of each other (for load-balancing purposes etc.) you can let only one app to do migrations so your database won't lose track of your migrations.

But if you have two different apps, it is difficult to maintain the state of your database healthy. Django also uses some sessions (built-in auth sessions etc.) in the database where you can lost your control. In that case, you can create a shared app, let it visible to your both projects and let all the database migrations be handled from there.

Comment: Sorry, I only have one database. Both apps are connected to the same one, and I essentially just want to disable all database changes resulting from one.